# Sending the correct NSNumber message for float or double data types?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnumber, scalar, cgfloat

Being the thoughtful (and really good-looking) developer that I am, I always use `CGFloat` when assigning `float`/`double` values, and the same goes for `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` when dealing with `int`/`long` values. A thing that's been nagging me for awhile, though, is the fact that I don't know which type to request when I need to unwrap a `CGFloat` (or `NSInteger`, etc.) value from an `NSNumber` object.

I can send either a `floatValue` or `doubleValue` message to get back a primitive type, but since I'm using `CGFloat`, I'm not sure of the actual type I need. I've been thinking of ways around this, but my ideas seem like pretty bloated solutions to something seemingly simple.

**Idea 1:**

```
CGFloat myFloatOrDouble = 4.5;

// I generally use boxed expressions to create NSNumber objects, so I
// don't have to choose between -numberWithFloat: or -numberWithDouble:

NSNumber *objectValue = @(myFloatOrDouble);
CGFloat scalarValue;

#if __LP64__
    scalarValue = numberValue.doubleValue;
#else
    scalarValue = numberValue.floatValue;
#endif
```

**Idea 2:**

```
NSNumber *objectValue = @4.5;
CGFloat scalarValue;

if ( sizeof(CGFloat) == sizeof(float) ) { 
    scalarValue = numberValue.floatValue;
} else {
    scalarValue = numberValue.doubleValue;
}
```

These are just some ideas off the top of my head, but they both seem a lot more complicated than I would assume they need to be.

So what's the best way to get a `#define`d type from an `NSNumber` object? Am I overthinking this? Am I missing something? Or did I actually just ask a good question?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Your "issue" simply proves that OO doesn't solve all programming problems ;)  NSNumber represents a "number", and it also remembers the type of the original primitive type where it has been initialized from (see `objCType`) That's it.

Comment: CGFloat should be used for floating point numbers _in graphics calculations_. CG = Core Graphics. For general use, use double _unless you have a very good reason that you can justify to use float_. Apart from that, CGFloat aCGFloat = [aNumber doubleValue] works just fine.